# TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null en React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Tengo el un proyecto react y  me sale el error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null

Cuando intento agregar una clase aun elemento HTML identificado con un ID

Sinceramente no se que estoy haciendo mal. La idea es que al hacer clic se agrege la clase css sobre el elemento.

Código JavaScript:

```
function AnimacionAnswers(){
  document.getElementById('correcta').classList.add('questionCorrect');
}
```

Codigo Html y React:

```
export default function Answers() {
  return (
    <div className="botones">
      <div className="row justify-content-center align-items-center">
        <div id="correcta" className="col-6 btn-respuestas" onClick={AnimacionAnswers()}>A. Respuestas</div>
        <div className="col-6 btn-respuestas">B. Respuestas</div>
      </div>
      <div className="row justify-content-center align-items-center">
        <div className="col-6 btn-respuestas">C. Respuestas</div>
        <div className="col-6 btn-respuestas">D. Respuestas</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estás ejecutando/invocando la función `AnimacionAnswers()` en el `onClick`. Deberías poner la referencia de la función, es decir,  `AnimacionAnswers` sin los parentesis y cuando ocurra el evento click ya se invocará a la función `AnimacionAnswers`.

```javascript
export default function Answers() {
  return (
    <div className="botones">
      <div className="row justify-content-center align-items-center">
        <div id="correcta" className="col-6 btn-respuestas" onClick={AnimacionAnswers}>A. Respuestas</div>
        <div className="col-6 btn-respuestas">B. Respuestas</div>
      </div>
      <div className="row justify-content-center align-items-center">
        <div className="col-6 btn-respuestas">C. Respuestas</div>
        <div className="col-6 btn-respuestas">D. Respuestas</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

En react no se recomienda acceder elementos del DOM directamente, sino que deberías usar [Refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html).

Comment: Muchas gracias funciono bien voy a revisar lo que me comentas de las Refs, no lo conocía dado que soy nuevo en este tema de React.